# How would I send user input data to PHP & send data from one PHP page to another PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am currently creating a basic maths website where it would ask the user to solve a multiply question.

I'm planning to have the HTML layed out like:

```html
1*8 = <input type="number" maxlength="3" name="answer1"><br>
2*9 = <input type="number" maxlength="3" name="answer2"><br>
4*4 = <input type="number" maxlength="3" name="answer3"><br>
<button type="button">Check Answers</button>
<p></p>
```

This HTML code is generated by some PHP code:

```
<?php
    $t = 0;

    for ($n = 1; $n <= 10; $n++) {

        $a = rand(1, 10);
        $b = rand(1, 10);

        echo $a . "*" . $b . " = <input type=\"number\" maxlength=\"3\" name=\"answer" . $n . "\"><br>";

        $t = $a * $b;
    }
?>
```

Now that is generated, I worked out what the total would be of the $a and $b (random numbers):

```
$t = $a * $b;
```

For the HTML button I wanted it so when the user clicks it, it would check all the input boxs and see if what they inputted = $t
Forgetting all validation, all I want to get working for now is the very basics.

I've got further with this using ajax to create a on-click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'calcc.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $("p").text(data);
            }
       });
   });
});
```

I've been messing around with it for a while now. I worked out that I would need to use $_SESSION or something similar to save the value of $t from before, but I can't seem to work out how it would all work, I keep getting errors of long repeated arrays and I have little idea how I would extract the information I want.

Another problem I am having is retrieving the users input upon the on-click, I have used POST and GET before but when I click the submit button it will act in a way where the page would reload and change all of the random numbers.

I preferably wanted to solve this in PHP. This has been bothering me for a while I just wanted to see if any of you had any great ideas of how I could make this work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions for your problem.

- The first one ( and most simple ) is retrieving your $_POST­[] parameters in the same script and executing the code when you receive a $_POST[] parameter that isn't empty.
- The second solution ( the one that you are using here ) is to use AJAX.
  I looked at your code and have some adjustements.

  `$(document).ready(function( e ){
      //Add an preventDefault on your event in order to not do the submit of the form.
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $("button").click(function(){
          //Get all the data from your form
          var data = $(form).serialize();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              //send the data with the ajax.
              // You can retrieve it in your php through $_POST['name of form field']
              data: data,
              url: 'calcc.php',
              success: function(data) {
                  $("p").text(data);
              }
          });
      });
   });`

I hope this helps you :)
Comment if you would like some more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I would put $a and $b in input fields too. They could be readonly, or even hidden. In this case your php script gets your random $a and $b and the result from the user. Your php script can now validate the result.
Tell me if you need some code.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what your getting at, I would put the $a and $b random numbers on the HTML page along with the users input. I could get it all at once, and calculate the answer on the second PHP script (on-click) one. Basically another method instead of $_SESSION. Then the only issue I have is calling it to PHP. Thank you :)